# React Starter Kit and Material UI: userAgent should be supplied in the muiTheme context for server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, material-ui, react-starter-kit

With the [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit), I add [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) as follows:

```
npm install material-ui --save
```

and the following import to a component:

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';
```

and:

```
<RaisedButton label="Default" />
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: Material-UI: userAgent should be supplied in the muiTheme context for server-side rendering.

According to Material UI's [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/server-rendering), it says I'd need to address three things:

1. autoprefixer and the user agent
2. process.env.NODE_ENV

What code should I put in and where exactly, specifically with the React Starter Kit?

P.S. [this solution](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/pull/414) does not work for me  :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me. Add this to `server.js`:

```
global.navigator = { userAgent: 'all' };
```

Then verify that you see multiple vendor prefixes used like in this screengrab showing `-webkit` and `-ms` both being used:

[image]

Comment: This solution will lead for invalid checksum and `display:-webkit-box,-moz-box,-ms-flexbox...`
please be careful, right now it will break your client behavior for support inline style prefixer which is trust the userAgent

Comment: Yes @IdanGozlan, I think [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43958563/6226738) is better.

Answer (score 6):

> When using Material-UI with server rendering, we must use the same environment for the server and the client. This has two technical implications.

*as you seen on [MaterialUI documentation](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/599a5327a015147699e6ef742b1939426b6b8d0b/docs/src/app/components/pages/get-started/serverRendering.md) page*

You need to provide the same user-agent for both server and browser contexts as you seen it in documentation, but, I strongly discourage you to provide a "all" user-agent, since you will serve a lot of unnecessary code to your end-user.

Instead you can easily follow MaterialUI doc and pass user-agent value contained in **http request headers**.

With an **express or koa** server

```
global.navigator = global.navigator || {};
global.navigator.userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'] || 'all';
```

I just checked [it has been added to the ReactStarterKit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/server.js#L31) (not tested myself) in `src/server.js`

```
global.navigator = global.navigator || {};
global.navigator.userAgent = global.navigator.userAgent || 'all';
```

Comment: This will absolutely *not* work correctly server-side, as node can be servicing multiple requests concurrently (for different browsers), thereby overwriting the global value of `global.navigator` to be incorrect mid-cycle.

Answer (score 4):

This should fix it

```
import themeDecorator from 'material-ui/lib/styles/theme-decorator';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/lib/styles/getMuiTheme';

class MyComponent extends Component {
 render() {
   return (<RaisedButton label="Default" />);
  }
}

export default themeDecorator(getMuiTheme(null, { userAgent: 'all' }))(MyComponent);
```

Comment: I'm told to use MuiThemeProvider instead because themeDecorator has been deprecated.

Comment: I agree that you should use `MuiThemeProvider` but `getMuiTheme(null, { userAgent: 'all' })` still works, an in my opinion it's way more elegant than declaring a global variable.

Comment: Hi @RomanStarkov and GiladArtzi, I think you can do it [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43958563/6226738).

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `global.navigator = { userAgent: 'all' };` at the top of your `server.js` file (Node.js entry point).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried adding that at the very top (1st line) of `server.js` and again after all the imports - still getting the same warning.

Comment: I had a look in the code and noticed that we'd need `global.navigator.userAgent = 'all'` not `global.navigator = ''` or `global.navigator = 'all'`. Will mention this in the GitHub discussion.

Answer (score 3):

The working (and the cleanest) solution for me is short and simple:

```
getMuiTheme({userAgent: (typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.userAgent) || 'all' })
```

Example (from my test app):

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme({userAgent: (typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.userAgent) || 'all' })}>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MyApplication/>
    </Provider>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete, throws  ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Comment: Wrong. `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

Comment: Hi @ThomasModeneis and Green, I think this solution is correct and working too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43958563/6226738

Comment: its supposed to be `global.navigator` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using KoaJS server you should install [koa-useragent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-useragent) and then use this before server side rendering:

```
  global.navigator = global.navigator || {};
  global.navigator.userAgent = this.state.userAgent.source || 'all';
```

It worked for me !