# Material-UI : How to properly set userAgent for server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm getting this warning :

```
    Material-UI: userAgent should be supplied in the muiTheme 
    context for server-side rendering
```

with the following server side rendering setup, what am I doing wrong :

```
    match({routes: R(), location}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error("error: "+ error)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
        console.error("redirect to " + redirectLocation)
    } else if (renderProps) {

        const theme = getMuiTheme({userAgent: "all"})

        page = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
            </Provider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    } else {
        console.error("location nof found: '"+ location +"'")
    }
    })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481084/react-starter-kit-and-material-ui-useragent-should-be-supplied-in-the-muitheme

Comment: I am having the same exact problem.  From material-ui documentation, it seems that the "all" user agent should work but it doesn't.  Also, double check that your environment is the same for server and client as described in their documentation. http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/server-rendering

Answer (score 2):

In this [Razzle Material UI Styled Example](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example) project I am setting it this way:

[server.js](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L20):

```
renderToString(<Application userAgent={request.headers['user-agent']} />)
```

[client.js](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example/blob/master/src/client.js#L6):

```
render(<Application userAgent={navigator.userAgent} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

[Main.js](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example/blob/master/src/application/Main.js#L27):

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(properties, context) {
        super(properties, context)

        this.muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
            userAgent: properties.userAgent
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={this.muiTheme}></MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

It works well and I think it is correct too.